# How to include 2 different Variables as Property and Value for a third Variable in Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, variables, properties

```
var A = $(this).attr("id") //result is a string

var B = $(this).attr("id") //result is another string from a different id

var C = {
 A: B      //I want to use A as Property and B as Value
};
```

when `console.log(C)` is made, JS console says that A is undefined. Why is this so?
//How can I use A as Property and B as Value as Object inside variable C then for Javascript and jQuery? //Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use brackets in property:

```
var C = { [A]: B };
```

Comment: Hi I tried your suggestion but JS Chrome console tells me that A is not defined. Any suggestion make A defined? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using the brackets syntax:

```
var C = {};
C[A] = B;
```

Or you can use the "Computed Property Name" ES6 feature:

```
var C = { [A]: B };
```

Comment: Hi I tried your suggestion but JS Chrome console tells me that A is not defined. Any suggestion make A defined? Thank you.

Comment: Could you post on jsfiddle or codepen the complete script to check it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to achieve something like this:

```
var a = 'something';
var b = 'else';

// example var c = { something: "else" };
```

if so, then it's super easy without advanced es6 experimental feats ;)

just (I'm using es6 template literals - but you can do with normal string concat):

```
 var c = JSON.parse(`{"${a}":"${b}"}`);
```